# How do I curl this post?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, access-token

I am trying to get an access Token from google api using code below,

```
$grant = urlencode("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer") . "&assertion=" . $jwtSign;
$postfields = array('Host' => 'www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'POST' => '/oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1', 'grant_type' => $grant);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

### but I am getting error saying. Please help me what's wrong

```
{
 "error": "invalid_request",
 "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to write some code/make an effort to code it yourself. We unfortunately only provide code help, not writing it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `grant_type` parameter now has become a concatenation of `urn:..:jwt-bearer` and the assertion. They should be provided as separate parameters in the call to the token endpoint.

You're also mixing setting header fields and providing POST parameters.

Lastly, providing an array to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` setting will make the `Content-Type` change to `multipart/form-data`.

Rather use:

```
    $postfields = array(
      'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion' => $jwtSign
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: thanks Hans but do you mean like this $postfields = array('Host' => 'www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'POST' => '/oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1', 'grant_type' => urlencode("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"),'assertion' => $jwtSign);

Comment: It's working now but with an error saying  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type

Comment: "invalid grant_type" or "invalid_grant"?

Comment: {
 "error": "invalid_request",
 "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&amp;assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9vYXV0aDIvdjMvdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3ByZWFkc2hlZXRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmVlZHMiLCJpYXQiOjE0MzY0NDk1NDIsImV4cCI6MTQzNjQ1MzE0MiwiaXNzIjoiMTQ0MTk5ODUwNTcxLTkycGEycTA4cHZhbGszN21pNnJocWNlNTFhMTVxOW5iQGRldmVsb3Blci5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIn0."
}

Comment: it shows that you're not using the code that I provided which separates the `grant_type` and the `assertion` parameters

Comment: I am getting this by using your code {
 "error": "invalid_grant",
 "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

Comment: that means the curl request is fine now; the contents of the JWT assertion that you send are not, but that is another question/topic; fwiw: you should follow the guidelines in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount